# Why is syslog not logging where I tell it to log?

Tags: macos

I've configured syslogd like so:

```
*.debug /var/log/messages
```

I want pretty much everything logged in `/var/log/messages`.

When I run

```
syslog -s hello
```

I get the message showing up in `/var/log/message`.

I tried restarting syslog using

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist
ps -x | grep [s]yslog
```

to check that syslog is not running, then

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist
```

to restart.

I checked `/etc/syslog.conf` to make sure it doesn't change, and it doesn't. Still I get messages logged to `/var/log/message`.

Is there another place to set this?

Comment: [`/etc/asl.conf`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/asl.conf.5.html) is also used to configure *syslogd*, but the storage files it specifies are not normal “plain text” log files. Do you perhaps have an embedded NUL character before the last `s` in your `syslog.conf` line? I can’t really imagine how it would happen “naturally”, but I was able to reproduce something similar with the line `*.* /tmp/message<00>s` (where the `<00>` is actually a single NUL character instead of the literal four displayed).

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of `asl.conf`. The actual problem was a newline, so you were close.

Comment: @user6385 Good diagnosis. Yes, now that you point it out, it was easy to spot the no-final-newline bug in `get_line_from_file` in [syslogd.tproj/daemon.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/syslog/syslog-100.2/syslogd.tproj/daemon.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. After using `vi` to create the file instead of a python script, I noticed that it was logging as expected. I did a `diff` of the files and noticed one had a newline while the other did not. Apple must remove the last character of the file expecting it to be a newline, which is why without the newline it logged to `/var/log/message` instead of `/var/log/messages`. I have fixed the python script. Your note about the tab made me try the `diff` on the file, so thanks!

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's an attempt to comment on a previous answer. Please use comments to respond or ask further questions. Answers are for solutions to the question. If your user-level is too low, finishing the tutorials will give you sufficient privileges.

Comment: @Greg I think we'll have to live with a new user trying to help. It does add some thinking and I'd have given the solved check mark to che2cbs, but I'm glad that the solved check mark lets anyone know that the OP is happy with the knowledge they have.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm the following worked on my Mac running 10.6.7:

I added the following line to /etc/syslog.conf (where `<tab>` is a tab character):

```
*.debug<tab>/var/log/messages
```

I HUP'd the syslogd process using `sudo kill -HUP <syslogd pid>`.

And tested it with `logger -p debug test_msg` and `syslog -s hello`.

syslog created /var/log/messages on the fly as I used the logger and syslog commands.

The man page for syslog.conf(5) specifies the use of tabs between the fields.  However, I tried using a single space instead and that worked as well.  Based on the man pages for syslog and syslogd, /etc/syslog.conf appears to be the only configuration file you need to worry about.