# store local1 syslog messages in /var/log/local1.log

Tags: macos, logs

I would like to have syslog messages for the local1 facility stored in a file `/var/log/local1.log`. I've tried managing `/etc/asl.conf` but can't figure out how to modify it. It seems that Apple is no longer using a standard syslog or rsyslog.

I tried the approach described in [Why is syslog not logging where I tell it to log?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13888/why-is-syslog-not-logging-where-i-tell-it-to-log) and it no longer works.

Is it even possible to do this anymore under MacOS? If not, is there a simple how-to that shows how to log to local1 and get the log messages?